# cómo fusionar dos arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript

De ante mano pido disculpas porque tal vez no es la forma de preguntar más acertada.

quiero llegar a "meter" dos objetos en un objeto, para que el objeto padre tenga dos objetos hijos y este a su vez tengan sus respectivas propiedades

```
let var1 = {"numero": 2, "letra": 'a'};
let var2 = {"numero": 3, "letra": 'b'};
```

lo que estoy buscando es algo que al imprimirlo tenga una estructura así

```
let var 3 = [var1, var2]
```

y que al imprimirlo en un console.log() lo pueda hacer como

```
console.log(var3.var1.numero)
```

y me imprima // 2

```
console.log(var3.var2.letra)
```

y me imprima // b

muchas gracias

pd: algo así

```
var [
   {var1 = {"numero": 2, "letra": 'a'}},
   {var2 = {"numero": 3, "letra": 'b'}}
   ]
```

Comment: `let var3 = [{var1}, {var2}]`

Comment: Si sabes que son objetos ¿por que en el titulo pones "arrays"?

Answer (score 1):

Primero, la tercer variable va sin el espacio.
Para eso necesitas hacer:

```
let var3 = {var1,var2}
```